# Best way to clone a git repository when authenticating via ssh key forwarding

Tags: git, ansible, git-clone

Prerequisites:

- Host & git authentication happens via ssh key
- ssh key forwarding is enabled
- Every user of our team uses a dedicated user account - it is not possible to log in via headless user account

Now we want to deploy an application from a git repository. This should be simple but it's not.

```
- name: Clone app repo
  git:
    repo: githost:org/repo.git
    dest: /some/location
    version: HEAD
    force: yes
    ssh_opts: -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
  notify:
    - Restart app
```

<sup><sub>*githost* is an entry in our .ssh/config</sub></sup>

This above task works. But the repository is (of course) cloned as the user who executed the playbook. What we need instead is:

- All files should be owned by a headless user, let's call him `zaphod`
- Only `zaphod` is allowed to **read** the files. We're talking about 0600/0700 permissions.

The following task will not work, because by using `become` we will lose the forwarded ssh key and therefore git authentication will fail:

```
- name: Clone app repo
  git:
    repo: githost:org/repo.git
    dest: /some/location
    version: HEAD
    force: yes
    ssh_opts: -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
  notify:
    - Restart app
  become: yes
  become_user: zaphod
```

The following variation would first call a handler which changes ownership of the checkout before (re)starting the application:

```
- name: Clone app repo
  git:
    repo: githost:org/repo.git
    dest: /some/location
    version: HEAD
    force: yes
    ssh_opts: -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
  notify:
    - Fix ownership
    - Restart app
```

This works once. But if you run the playbook a 2nd time the git task fails because the user who runs the play does not have permissions to modify the clone.

We have a very ugly solution:

- Clone into /tmp/foo
- Fix ownership of /tmp/foo
- `rm -rf /some/location`
- `mv /tmp/foo /some/location`
- Finally (re)start application

The problem with this is that this would:

- Trigger a restart every single time the playbook is executed
- The Ansible summary shows 5 changed tasks, even though nothing happened - except the restart which was not required in the first place

I'm a bit picky here, but I do only want to have changed states if something really changed, so in a perfect world not even the git task would have a changed state. And for this I do not see a solution. Because we require that the cloned files are only accessible by `zaphod` - but `zaphod` himself is not able to clone the repo. So there has to be some manipulation is some form resulting in changes.

Any suggestions how this can be improved in a clean way? I don't want to add another 20 tasks shuffling around with temporary copies, temporarily changing permissions, comparing files manually and so forth...

Of course a custom written module would be able to deal with all this - but I'm more interested in something that does not take 2 days in development and battle testing. ;-)

Comment: Can't you create a `group` and add all those that need to manipulate the same repo into the same group. You also wouldn't need "another 20 tasks" you could probably get away with one more (`chmod` the repo) - see here for more details http://serverfault.com/questions/26954/how-do-i-share-a-git-repository-with-multiple-users-on-a-machine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to deploy an application/webpage by simply cloning the repo containing the stuff you need rather than needing to be able to then push any changes back to the repo from that server.

If that's the case then you could get away with a local task to [`git archive`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive) the repo into a tarball or something and then use [`unarchive`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/unarchive_module.html) to copy the resulting archive to the target machine and unpack it. `unarchive` will allow you to set the permissions and ownership.

So your play could look something like:

```
- name: locally clone repo
  git:
    repo: githost:org/repo.git
    dest: /some/tmp/location
    version: HEAD
    force: yes
  delegate_to: localhost
  changed_when: false #

- name: archive app repo
  command: git archive --format zip --output /path/to/archive master
    chdir: /some/tmp/location
  delegate_to: localhost
  changed_when: false

- name: unarchive app repo
  unarchive:
    src: /path/to/archive
    dest: /some/location
    owner: zaphod
    mode: 0700
    creates: /some/location
  notify:
    - Restart app
```

Comment: While this would work well in a pinch, it would force a download and upload even when the git repo hasn't changed, right?

Answer (score 0):

Building up upon @ydaetskcoR 's answer, the below version works as well:

```
- name: locally clone repo
  git:
    repo: githost:org/repo.git
    dest: /some/tmp/location
    version: HEAD
    force: yes
  delegate_to: localhost

- name: archive app repo
  archive: 
    path: /some/tmp/location
    dest: /some/tmp/archive.tgz
  delegate_to: localhost

- name: unarchive app repo
  unarchive:
    src: /some/tmp/archive.tgz
    dest: /some/remote/location
    owner: zaphod
    mode: 0700
  notify:
    - Restart app
```

Comment: Git understands itself better than `archive` does.  `git archive` can work with/without ignored files and use explicit refs for export.